# How to write a tuple with spread type in Zod

Tags: typescript, zod

In TypeScript, you would write:

```js
type A = ["A", ...string[]];
```

How would you define that type definition using [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod)?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBALzgMyhEcBECIBNMDcAUDAJ5gCmcAggM60WwCiAjgK4CGANgDzUA0cAEIA+OAF4acCgA8YFAHa5awuAH44ACiHS5i5VI0wobKgC4U3BgEo4F5FYrEiAehdxcFWsCgVcJcipqCTgAbUxqTEEAOljaY2AFAHNQgF1U5zc4AGM2KF8FGCJsiAV4xGDJBGiYNjAuCk1Q6q5geShuTQjMa0Fq+KhEpM1raI58jlIR1OtM91z8xXhfWjYuIrJKOAAlLzX4KujE5EYeTYoIZAqRYjg4LIA9NSIX87gAYQALCmyAaxC6AxmOxuHxBLtVusbkQ7rDHmogA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`zod` documentation](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#tuples) on tuples:

> A variadic ("rest") argument can be added with the `.rest` method.

so a schema for your use case would look like:

```js
const schema = z.tuple([z.literal('A')]).rest(z.string())
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBALzgMyhEcBECIBNMDcAUDAJ5gCmcAggM60WwCiAjgK4CGANgDzUA0cAEIA+OAF4acCgA8YFAHa5awuAH44ACiHS5i5VI0wobKgC4U3BgEo4F5FYrEiAehdxcFWsCgVcJcipqCTgAbUxqTEEAOljaY2AFAHNQgF1U5zc4AGM2KF8FGCJsiAV4xGDJBGiYNjAuCk1Q6q5geShuTQByai7rVOto33jNavioRKTNa2siOazc-MV4YbYuIrJKOAAlLzX4KujE5EYeTYoIZAqRYjg4LIA9NTmArYBhAAsKbIBrELoGMx2Nw+IJdrR9jciHcYY81EA)